# Lenght of the ElGamal cipher

Tags: elgamal-encryption

Ok, it's kind of stupid question, but I want to make sure.

What is the length of the ElGamal cipher? It's equal to the size of 2 elements of the cyclic group, right? But lengths of elements are NOT always the same, right?

Toy example:

We pick p = 23, q = 11 (p = 2q+1), our generator is 18, so 
G = {18,2,13,4,3,8,6,16,12,9,1}. Sekret key x is 6 (a random form {1,q-1}), h = g^x mod p = 8.

Now is the fun part:

1) Encryption of m = 18 with  r = 8 is (16,3)

2) Encryption of m = 18 with  r = 7 is (6,9)

Am I getting different length ciphers because it's the toy example or what? Padding? All group elements have identical length? I haven't noticed any length difference in the real ElGamal implementation.

Comment: There's about a $\frac{2}{256}$ of one of the parts being a byte shorter. Padding may be applied depending on the encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One common possibility is that your non-toy ElGamal cipher express integers as fixed-width octet strings, of width large enough for any element in the base field; that could be with [I2OSP of PKCS#1v2.2](https://www.emc.com/collateral/white-papers/h11300-pkcs-1v2-2-rsa-cryptography-standard-wp.pdf#page=8) or equivalent, but there are a number of other (less common) ways.

Another possibility is that you did not try hard enough to find shorter ciphertext for your non-toy ElGamal cipher. When [ASN.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One) representation of integers is used, the digit size is an octet, and for some parameters an integer might be under the maximum size with low probability, like down to about 1/256 ≈ 0.4%. Even with two integers, quite a few hundred attempts might be necessary to observe a ciphertext below the usual size. There are other conventions where observing shorter ciphertexts would require billions attempts.